# i use facing a issue in qml button

Tags: javascript, qt, button, qml

i was try to create a button in bottom menu but i was facing a issue if  i clicked a rect mouse area then the text is changing if i clicked the changed another function is working
i need a help how solve the issue
if i clicked gain then only gain options should be visible then if i clicked back every thing should be normal and also  in gain if i click 1x then how to integrated with another qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
width: 1920
height: 1080
visible: true
title: qsTr("Hello World")
Rectangle{
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height*0.1
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    color:"#D9D9D9"
    Rectangle{

        id:back
        height:parent.height
        width:parent.width/6
        color: "#D9D9D9"
        border.width:1.5
        border.color:"#b9bab8"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill:parent
            hoverEnabled:true
            onEntered: {
                back.color="#aba9a9"

            }
            onExited: {
                back.color="#D9D9D9"

            }
            onClicked: {

                gain.border.width=1
                 speed.border.width=1
                 filter.border.width=1
                 lead.border.width=1
                 setting.border.width=1
                gaintxt.text="Gain"
                speedtxt.text="Speed"
                filtertxt.text="Filter"
                leadtxt.text="Lead"
                settingtxt.text="Settings"
                btn()
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: backtxt
            text: qsTr("Back")
            font.pixelSize: 25
            font.family: nunito.name
            anchors.centerIn:parent
        }

    }

        Rectangle{

            id:gain
            height:parent.height
            width:parent.width/6
            color: "#D9D9D9"
            anchors.left: back.right
            state: "gain"
            border.width:1.5
            border.color:"#b9bab8"

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill:parent
                hoverEnabled:true
                onEntered: {
                    gain.color="#aba9a9"
                }
                onExited: {
                    gain.color="#D9D9D9"
                }


                onClicked: {
                    parent.border.width=3
                    speedtxt.text="1x(mm/mv)"
                    filtertxt.text="2x(mm/mv)"
                    leadtxt.text="3x(mm/mv)"
                    settingtxt.text="4x(mm/mv)"
                    gaintxt.font.bold = true
                    gaintxt.color = "#001E60"
                    //gain.state = (gain.state == "gain" ? "back" : "gain")



            }
            Text {
                id: gaintxt
                text: qsTr("Gain")
                font.family: nunito.name
                font.pixelSize: 25
                anchors.centerIn:parent

            }
    }
        Rectangle{
            id:speed
            height:parent.height
            width:gain.width
            color: "#D9D9D9"
            anchors.left: gain.right
            border.width:1.5
            border.color: "#b9bab8"
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill:parent
                hoverEnabled:true
                onEntered: {
                    speed.color="#aba9a9"
                }
                onExited: {
                    speed.color="#D9D9D9"
                }
                onClicked: {
                    parent.border.width=3
                    gaintxt.text="Speed"
                    speedtxt.text="5"
                    filtertxt.text="10"
                    leadtxt.text="25"
                    settingtxt.text="50"
                    gaintxt.font.bold = true
                    gaintxt.color = "#001E60"

                }
            }
            Text {
                id: speedtxt
                text: qsTr("Speed")
                font.pixelSize: 25
                font.family: nunito.name
                anchors.centerIn:parent
            }
    }

        Rectangle{
        id:filter
        height:parent.height
        width:gain.width
        color: "#D9D9D9"
        anchors.left: speed.right
        border.width:1.5
        border.color:"#b9bab8"
        MouseArea{
            id:filtermouse
            anchors.fill:parent
            hoverEnabled:true
            onEntered: {
                filter.color="#aba9a9"
            }
            onExited: {
                filter.color="#D9D9D9"
            }
            onClicked: {
                parent.border.width=3
                gaintxt.text="Filter"
                speedtxt.text="20"
                filtertxt.text="40"
                leadtxt.text="100"
                settingtxt.text="150"
                gaintxt.font.bold = true
                gaintxt.color = "#001E60"
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: filtertxt
            text: qsTr("Fliter")
            font.pixelSize: 25
            font.family: nunito.name
            anchors.centerIn:parent
        }

}
        Rectangle{
        id:lead
        height:parent.height
        width:gain.width
        color: "#D9D9D9"
        anchors.left: filter.right
        border.width:1.5
        border.color:"#b9bab8"
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill:parent
            hoverEnabled:true
            onEntered: {
                lead.color="#aba9a9"
            }
            onExited: {
                lead.color="#D9D9D9"
            }
            onClicked: {
                parent.border.width=3
                gaintxt.text="Lead"
                speedtxt.text="3"
                filtertxt.text="6"
                leadtxt.text="12"
                settingtxt.text=""
                gaintxt.font.bold = true
                gaintxt.color = "#001E60"

            }
        }
        Text {
            id: leadtxt
            text: qsTr("Lead")
            font.family: nunito.name
            font.pixelSize: 25
            anchors.centerIn:parent
        }

}
        Rectangle{
        id:setting
        height:parent.height
        width:gain.width
        color: "#D9D9D9"
        anchors.left: lead.right
        border.width:1.5
        border.color: "#b9bab8"
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill:parent
            hoverEnabled:true
            onEntered: {
                setting.color="#aba9a9"
            }
            onExited: {
                setting.color="#D9D9D9"
            }
            onClicked: {
                parent.border.width=3
                settingtxt.font.bold = true
                settingtxt.color = "#001E60"
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: settingtxt
            text: qsTr("Settings")
            font.family: nunito.name
            font.pixelSize: 25
            anchors.centerIn:parent


        }

}



}
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Rectangle with MouseArea when you could have used Button. Also @saivineeth if people are helping you with your problems, you need to upvote them, especially if you start using their answers in your follow up questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the various feedback, I did a major rewrite of the program.

- MyApp.qml - the parent application that has the StackView
- MainPage.qml - the main page that has the menu bar
- SettingsPage.qml - a mock settings page
- MainMenu.qml - contains the main menu bar
- GainMenu.qml - contains the gain menu bar
- SpeedMenu.qml - contains the speed menu bar
- LeadMenu.qml - contains the lead menu bar
- AppButton.qml - the big buttons on the menu bar

The refactor came about because I wanted to reduce complexity. The current implementations has these states:

- MainPage with [Gain] [Speed] [Filter] [Lead] [Settings] menu buttons
- MainPage with [Back] [1x] [2x] [3x] [4x] gain menu buttons
- MainPage with [Back] [5] [10] [25] [50] speed menu buttons
- MainPage with [Back] [20] [40] [100] [150] filter menu buttons
- MainPage with [Back] [3] [6] [12] lead buttons
- SettingsPage with [Back] button

Clicking on any of the buttons on the main menu will load either (1) a gain, speed, filter, or lead menu bar, (2) take you to the SettingsPage.

Clicking on the [Back] button will take you back to the MainPage and back to the main menu.

Click on any of the number buttons will set a property and then take you back to the MainPage and back to the main menu.

A StackView was used to navigate between MainPage.qml and SettingsPage.qml.

A Loader was used to load the various menus.

The `stackView` and `menuBar`, `gain`, `speed`, `filter`, and `lead` property's scope can be seen in multiple locations. This was necessary for the sub-page or the sub-menu to manipulate properties belonging to a parent page.

```
//MyApp.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Page {
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "MainPage.qml"
    }
}

//MainPage.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Page {
    id: mainPage

    property int gain: 0
    property int speed: 0
    property int filter: 0
    property int lead: 0
    
    header: Frame {
        Text { text: "MainPage" }
    }

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 10
        Frame {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text { text: "gain: " + gain + "x" }
        }
        Frame {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text { text: "speed: " + speed }
        }
        Frame {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text { text: "filter: " + filter }
        }
        Frame {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Text { text: "lead: " + lead}
        }
    }

    footer: Loader {
        id: menuBar
        source: "MainMenu.qml"
    }
}

//SettingsPage.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Page {
    header: Frame {
        Text { text: "SettingsPage" }
    }
    footer: Flow {
        AppButton {
            text: qsTr("Back")
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}

//MainMenu.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Flow {
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Gain")
        onClicked: {
            menuBar.source = "GainMenu.qml"
        }
    }
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Speed")
        onClicked: {
            menuBar.source = "SpeedMenu.qml"
        }
    }
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Filter")
        onClicked: {
            menuBar.source = "FilterMenu.qml"
        }
    }
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Lead")
        onClicked: {
            menuBar.source = "LeadMenu.qml"
        }
    }
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Settings")
        onClicked: stackView.push("SettingsPage.qml")
    }
}

//GainMenu.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Flow {
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Back")
        onClicked: back()
    }
    Repeater {
        model: [1,2,3,4]
        AppButton {
            text: modelData + "x"
            onClicked: {
                gain = modelData;
                back();
            }
        }
    }
    function back() {
        menuBar.source = "MainMenu.qml"
    }
}

//SpeedMenu.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Flow {
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Back")
        onClicked: back()
    }
    Repeater {
        model: [5, 10, 25, 50]
        AppButton {
            text: modelData
            onClicked: {
                speed = modelData;
                back();
            }
        }
    }
    function back() {
        menuBar.source = "MainMenu.qml"
    }
}

//FilterMenu.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Flow {
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Back")
        onClicked: back()
    }
    Repeater {
        model: [20, 40, 100, 150]
        AppButton {
            text: modelData
            onClicked: {
                filter = modelData;
                back();
            }
        }
    }
    function back() {
        menuBar.source = "MainMenu.qml"
    }
}

//LeadMenu.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Flow {
    AppButton {
        text: qsTr("Back")
        onClicked: back()
    }
    Repeater {
        model: [3, 6, 12]
        AppButton {
            text: modelData
            onClicked: {
                lead = modelData;
                back();
            }
        }
    }
    function back() {
        menuBar.source = "MainMenu.qml"
    }
}

//AppButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Button {
    width: 150
    height: 50
    background: Rectangle {
        color: pressed ? "#ddd" : checked ? "black" : "#ccc"
        border.color: "#aaa"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: how to contact you

Comment: @saivineeth it appears you were helped by the answer. Feel free to use StackOverflow to ask more QML questions. However, please try to improve your description of your problem and properly format, and indent your code snippets. It makes it easier to run/reproduce the problem.

Comment: TQ u for your response and i need a help but u r solution is right but i need it in another way if i click gain i should see back ,gain next gain options only not remaining text

Comment: @saivineeth I see that I misunderstood your requirements. It wasn't clearly stated. I have reworked the answer to implementing `menuGroup` which basically is a state variable for what buttons you want to see. The cool thing about that is we can implement some hierarchy. I don't know if this is the best way to do it. The other requirements aren't clear. The more information you provide, the more focused the answer can become.

Comment: It is really hard to reverse engineer your requirements from your code. It is painful for me to guess. Then you make a correction. I guess again. Then you make a correction. Howabout you describe clearly the bottom menu bar. Like you did just now, but also with all the different transitions? My answer is meant to serve as a guide to help you to the requirement you've described, but, if you have further detail, I think you should be more than capable of taking what you have been given and adapting it to your purpose. If it is beyond the scope of the question, feel free to create a new question.

Comment: hi i need a bottom menu bar which contains 1.back 2.gain 3.speed 4.filter 5.lead 6. setting and in gain option i need (1x,2x,3x,4x) ,speed option i need(5,10,25,50),filter option i need (20,40,100,150) lead  option i need (3,6,12)and settings option i need to open a application window which is present in same file if i click (gain,speed ,filter,lead ) first back button should be and gain name then gain options like that it should be word if i click any optioj in gain it should change the value in other file

Comment: It is not clear the function of the back button. Since you show it on the initial menu bar, it has no function. And, on the other menus, you do not have a back button. Also, it isn't clear if you want these menu changes but keep the rest of the application window the same or whether it can change. If it is the same, what is the rest of the application window doing?